Attempting to run a Minecraft server and I keep getting Error: unable to access jarfile
I'm trying to run a minecraft server and when I type the command:
java -Xmx1024M -xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.21.jar

and I get - Error: unable to access jarfile minecraft_server.1.21.jar...
I looked at a few post talking about permissions so I tried running cmd as administrator and even navigated to the file path to run it.
Edit:

This shows the file path of the server and path of the command I ran. what am I missing?
Also not sure if its helpful but I'm running a windows VM via proxmox.

if the file correct? is it in the same directory as the command is being run? what is the result of executing dir minecraft_server_1.21.jar (Windows) or ls -l minecraft_server_1.21.jar (Unix, linux, *nix)

File not found is the result. Also there was a typo in the original post for the command but i edited it.

I assume that you are on Windows and you open a Command Prompt window and enter the java command. The command in your question assumes that file minecraft_server.1.21.jar is in the same folder as the one that you issued the command from. Clearly it is not. Either navigate to the folder containing the JAR file before entering the command, or write the full path to the JAR file in the command itself.

The java command you are running is looking for a file named minecraft_server.1.12.jar. When you look at your file explorer the only files possible for it to even find are run.bat and server.jar (Based on the original screenshot). So you have to have these match. Either by renaming the jar file or changing the command.
Ps: Highly recommend turning on file extensions.
Another thing I'n noticing is the use of pause in the same command as the java command. This pause command won't ever run. In your run.bat it should look something like this.
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar jarfile.jar nogui
pause


And yes the jar file and script mojang gives on their website don't match. It's vert fun.

check ur typos, maybe it's not "1.21" but "1_21"? Or use the absolute path?

I had a typo in the original post but I edited it. What I was running is now what's in the post.
